# Connecting an ATA disk into an e-SATA input?

Tags: sata, esata, ata

I´ve build a new PC and wanted to add my older disks to it (they are not SATA, but ATA).
Is there a way to add them as an external drive using the external e-sata input that I have in my case?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [ATA (IDE) to SATA convertors](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=pata+to+sata+adapter&tag=googhydr-21&index=computers&hvadid=14380643636&hvpos=1t2&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1931945059185002724&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&ref=pd_sl_60vgo6o7eo_b). You can put the old drive in an external case with power, plug it into such a convertor and connect that to the eSATA port. (SATA and eSATA are compatible).

But seriously, unless you need to rescue data from an old and probably much smaller and much slower disk and probaly louder drive, do not bother. Just copy the data once and put the old disk away.

Answer (score 1):

Put your PATA drive into a eSATA enclosure that supports PATA drives.